# Add join and search in columns for any string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these Postgres tables:

```
create table deals_new
(
    id                  bigserial primary key,
    slip_id             text,
    deal_type           integer,
    timestamp           timestamp,
    employee_id         bigint
        constraint employee_id_fk
            references common.employees
);

create table twap
(
    id                 bigserial     primary key,
    deal_id            varchar          not null,
    employee_id        bigint
        constraint fk_twap__employee_id
            references common.employees,
    status             integer
);

create table common.employees
(
    id              bigint primary key,
    first_name      varchar(150),
    last_name       varchar(150)
);
```

I use this SQL query:

```
select d.*, t.id as twap_id 
from common.deals_new d 
    left outer join common.twap t on 
        t.deal_id = d.slip_id and
        d.timestamp between '11-11-2021' AND '11-11-2021' and
        d.deal_type in (1, 2) and
        d.quote_id is null
where d.employee_id is not null
order by d.timestamp desc, d.id
offset 10
limit 10;
```

How I extend this SQL query to search also in table `employees` by employee id and filter the result by any character found in table columns `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: Why not add another join?

Comment: Please, add some sample data, and desired output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the new table using `employee_id`:

```
SELECT d.*, t.id as twap_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM common.deals_new d 
JOIN common.employees e ON e.id = d.employee_id -- Joining employees table
LEFT OUTER JOIN common.twap t on 
        t.deal_id = d.slip_id AND
        d.timestamp between '11-11-2021' AND '11-11-2021' AND
        d.deal_type in (1, 2) AND
        d.quote_id is null
WHERE ( -- Filtering based on first_name or last_name
            e.first_name LIKE '%John%'
            OR e.last_name LIKE '%Doe%'
        )
ORDER BY d.timestamp desc, d.id
OFFSET 10
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: When you do an (INNER) JOIN on `employees`, there will be no need to check this: `d.employee_id is not null`

Comment: @Luuk agreed, I updated the answer

Comment: For some reason I don't get the result filtered - nothing happens no matter what I set here `e.first_name LIKE '%John%'` for searched string?

Comment: I tested the code. Do you know how I can display `e.first_name` and `e.last_name` as columns into the result?

Comment: @user1285928 yes, I updated the query in my response to ass them to the SELECT

Comment: @user1285928 if I answered your original question, can you please accept my answer as the correct answer

Comment: One more question: How I have to send params into this part of the code: '%John%' maybe `:param` but how to include `%`?